# What is "cached" in the top command?

Tags: memory, top

When running `top`, I get:

```
top - 09:10:52 up 18:37,  1 user,  load average: 1.56, 1.33, 1.15
Tasks:  39 total,   1 running,  38 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.6%sy,  1.0%ni, 92.5%id,  5.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4194304k total,  3045460k used,  1148844k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  2256128k cached
```

See the part: 2256128k cached?  What exactly does that mean?

I am comparing two VPS from two provider, this one always has a large amount there (70% of the used memory) and the other VPS provider always shows 0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That number before cached is the amount of physical memory that is being used by cache buffers for your filesystems.

It's [not actually](https://www.linux.com/learn/uncover-meaning-tops-statistics) related to SWAP, despite being on the "Swap:" line.

To verify my answer with a little experiment try the following:

Run top and note the value of 'cached'. Now run

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/trick bs=1M count=128
```

if you run top again you'll notice that 'cached' has grown by **128M**

Now remove the file

```
rm ~/trick
```

Run top again and you'll see 'cached' has dropped by **128M**

So for Mem:

`total = used + free` and

`used = <all apps> + buffers + cached`

(where buffers is basically [metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14671569/32453) for the cached).  A bit confusing of a UI.

Comment: and I can influence this anyhow, e.g. limit it or disable completely?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?! what shall you do with?! its about how file system cache in phyiscal memory.

Comment: Cause most of the filesystem is a DB, the DB has its own cache, so I assume it would be good to limit this part somehow.

Comment: You can do it with some search but i don't advice you. This will limit the performance of th FS

Answer (score 128):

the Linux kernel will use available memory for disk caching, unless it's required by a running program.

This is considered good; say you have 4 GB RAM, and your programs are using only 1 GB. The other 3 GB are going to waste. Despite the "feel-good" impression from knowing you're only using 25% of your memory, the counterpart is that the other 75% is going unused. So the kernel uses that for caching files which significantly improves performance. It's automatic; unlike older operating systems you don't need to decide how much to devote to disk cache, or manually configure it.

"The Linux disk cache is very unobtrusive. It uses spare memory to greatly increase disk access speeds, and without taking any memory away from applications. A fully used store of ram on Linux is efficient hardware use, not a warning sign."

This is such a common question that there's an entire website devoted to it:

http://www.linuxatemyram.com

The website even has a way to empty the disk cache so you can then run some applications and see how much faster they are with the cache enabled :)

Comment: Love the answer, but due to lack in reputation I can't upgrade it (yet). Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm just glad to be of help. Hope the information is useful!

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. Oh, well . . . :(

Comment: definitely should be the accepted answer. linuxatemyram is great info!