# Why does running the "find" command a second time complete quicker than the first time?

Tags: command-line, bash, find

When I run `time find ~` the first time, meaning the first time I run `find` in a session, it takes longer than than when run a second time. Why is that?

First run:

```
real    0m12.410s
user    0m0.424s
sys     0m1.287s
```

Second run:

```
real    0m0.988s
user    0m0.214s
sys     0m0.405s
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/638946/why-is-find-running-incredible-fast-if-run-twice ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind, thanks. Very elaborate answer and comments  there!

Answer (score 3):

The [link provided by Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142626/why-does-running-the-find-command-a-second-time-complete-quicker-than-the-firs#comment1895036_1142626) titled [Why is [find] running incredible fast, if run twice?](https://superuser.com/q/638946/462117) and [What is “cached” in the top command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/198549/248158) cover the same issue.

Essentially, if free RAM is available, the kernel can use part of it to cache information. The memory used in this way can be made available to applications on demand.

[Linux ate my RAM](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html) explains terms such as  *available*, *buffer*, *free*, and *used*. It also provides the following command to clear "most of the disk cache":

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

To confirm that *find* is quicker the second time around, I ran `time find ~` for the first time:

```
real    0m10.765s
user    0m0.395s
sys     0m1.169s
```

And a second time to see the beneficial effect of memory caching:

```
real    0m1.119s
user    0m0.196s
sys     0m0.476s
```

Then I cleared cache with `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and ran `time find ~` again. Sure enough, the time was high again:

```
real    0m19.198s
user    0m0.457s
sys     0m1.425s
```

But, because of fresh caching, a run of *find* subsequently and expectedly, showed an improved time:

```
real    0m1.100s
user    0m0.199s
sys     0m0.484s
```

---

While reading about *cache*, I came across [Caching/preloading files on Linux into RAM](https://serverfault.com/questions/43383/caching-preloading-files-on-linux-into-ram#) and a couple of answers suggested [vmtouch - the Virtual Memory Toucher](https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/): it is described as a "Portable file system cache diagnostics and control" and is [in the repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=vmtouch&searchon=names) for Bionic and later.